# Is the Ext module $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(R/I^n,-)$ annihilated by a power of $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $I$ an ideal in $R$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module.

> Is, for all $i$ and $n$, the module $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(R/I^n,M)$ killed by a power of $I$?

I've read somewhere that this is true when $R$ is local and $I=\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal, but can someone explain why this is true and whether it is true in the above, more general, setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: let $N,M$ be any two $R$-modules ($R$ being an arbitrary commutative unital ring) and $J \subset R$ some ideal such that $JN=0$.

Then $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(N,M)$ is a cohomology group in the complex $\mathrm{Hom}_R(N,I_{\cdot})$ where $I_{\cdot}$ is an injective resolution. But obviously, every module in this complex is annihilated by $J$, so that the same holds for its cohomology.

So in your case, $I^n$ annihilates $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(R/I^n,M)$.